# how can i load a web view that it takes that it takes a URL from my back end?

Tags: javascript, flutter

I create a genealogical family tree with gojs master library on my backend and
I'm trying to show it on my web view in flutter but the container appears empty.
I changed localhost to 10.0.2.2 and I tried my IP address but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
Container(
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                            maxHeight: 650,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          ),
                          child: WebView(
                            initialUrl:
                                'http://10.0.2.2:3000/genocheck/arbre',
                            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                          )),
```

Browser:
[image: browser output]

Console output:
[image: console output]

Web View:

[image: web view]

Comment: can you reach it through the phone browser?

Comment: no i tried it now it doesn't work too

Comment: there you have your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your router's `3000` port is closed, try opening it.
Check this [How to Forward or Open Ports on Your Router?](https://www.purevpn.com/blog/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/#:%7E:text=Head%20over%20to%20your%20router%27s,8080%20to%20open%20port%208080.)

Comment: but it works on the navigator that's mean that there is no port issue and i already using the same port for other web services and it works

Comment: it works because the browser is on the same computer as the server, but to access another one you need to open the ports. As you commented above, the phone's own browser does not open.